# Match the lines with exactly two matches

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have a text file with short text strings:

```
what TIME is it
what TIME is in X if here it is TIME
```

I would like to find and print all the lines where the word ``TIME'' appears exactly twice.

With grep it is easy to find one or more with

```
grep "TIME" file.txt
```

I tried also

```
grep -E "TIME{2}" file.txt
awk '/TIME{2}/' file.txt
```

but I get only empty output. What can be the issue? How can this be solved?

What I know from regexes is that when we use *, it means 0 or more matches, if we use +, it means 1 or more matches. Finally, if we use {min,max}, then you are looking for min to max matches. Using {N} tells the engine to return exactly N matches.

Comment: You said "word" but you also said "string" so to clarify: what if the line was `abc FOOTIMEBAR def` - how many times does TIME appear in that line?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it in Perl, where you count the number of matches.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @matches = /TIME/g;
    print if @matches == 2;
}

__DATA__
what TIME is it
what TIME is in X if here it is TIME
```

Gives this output:

```
what TIME is in X if here it is TIME
```

Comment: Nice. As a one-liner, could be: `perl -ne 'print if s/TIME/TIME/g == 2' file`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'gsub(/TIME/,"&")==2' file
what TIME is in X if here it is TIME
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about quantifiers, the patterns they quantify must be consecutive. To answer your problem, you are better off with something like `.*?time.*?time.*`, case insensitive obviously.

https://regex101.com/r/wD4oT8/3

It means that `time` will occur twice and it may contain information on either side of any of the time. Note that this means that 3 and more mentions still works.

We can use the same thing, but write a lookahead at the start to assert that "time" is not mentioned more than twice. `(?!.*time.*time.*time)^.*?time.*?time.*`

as seen https://regex101.com/r/wD4oT8/4 .

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk -F 'TIME' 'NF==3' file
what TIME is in X if here it is TIME
```

Comment: OP wants TIME exactly twice.